Need help to prove that a variable is extracted using pattern matching from a pair (or a dependent pair) in Lean 4
everyone! I'm new to Lean4, and I'm practicing to write a proof.
I write a function that returns several values, proofs or functions, and I pack them in a nested dependent pair. I wanna create new variables for each of them for convenience, but I find that where those new variables come from seems not to be in the context.
Here is a simplified example, where the dependent pair is replaced by an independent pair:
example (a : Nat) :=
  let g : Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat := (a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4)
  let (a, b, c, d, e) := g
  -- let ⟨a, b, c, d, e⟩ := g -- Anonymous constructor does not work, either
  
  -- `rfl` here reports an error
  let h : e = g.snd.snd.snd.snd := rfl
  ()

And rfl reports an error like below:
type mismatch
  rfl
has type
  e = e : Prop
but is expected to have type
  e = g.snd.snd.snd.snd : Prop

And if I use simp tactic, like let h : e = g.snd.snd.snd.snd := by simp[e], it will report an error like:
invalid argument, variable is not a proposition or let-declaration

So it seems that a variable introduced in pattern is not regarded as a let-declaration.
A not-so-convenient solution
Though I find that codes like below do work, I'll have to write many lines if I need every part of the dependent pair, and I may need to repeat myself a lot of times.
example (a : Nat) :=
  let g : Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat := (a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4)
  let e := g.snd.snd.snd.snd
  let h : e = g.snd.snd.snd.snd := rfl
  ()


I updated my answer with a note at the bottom.  You can easily avoid nested dependent pairs as output by making a custom structure type, avoiding the difficulties you are facing with pattern matching on long patterns.

I'm not sure what your exact question is.  This seems more like a complaint or bug report. (And I think it would make sense to fill this as an issue on the Lean 4 repository.)
Using match with a hypothesis
But to the extent that your question is what can be done instead, here is at least one option.  This let using pattern matching is just syntax sugar for a match statement.  (You can see this if you #print your definition.  match supports a notation which adds the hypothesis h to the context, namely match h : exp with ....   I'm not aware of a similar option available for let.  (However, if then else, which is also similar to a match statement, does provide this hypothesis syntax.)  Using match, it would look like follows:
def foo (n : Nat) : Unit :=
  let g : Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat := (n, n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, n + 4)
  match hh : g with
  | (a, b, c, d, e) =>
    /-
    n : Nat
    g : Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat := (n, n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, n + 4)
    a b c d e : Nat
    hh : g = (a, b, c, d, e)
    ⊢ Unit
    -/
    let h : e = g.snd.snd.snd.snd := by rw [hh]
    ()

It isn't ideal.  The match is cumbersome, you have indent creep (although, you don't have to indent here), and the hypothesis hh : g = (a, b, c, d, e) isn't that easy to work with (notably, it isn't automatically available to rfl or simp).
Separate computation and proof
A different option would be to break things up.  Sometimes this is easier said than done, but you could break your definition up into a bunch of auxiliary results.  Even though inside the definition, Lean has trouble keeping track of the fact that e = g.snd.snd.snd.snd, it is still something you could prove later:
def baz (n : Nat) :=
  let g : Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat × Nat := (n, n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, n + 4)
  let (a, b, c, d, e) := g
  (g, e)

example (n : Nat) : (baz n).2 = (baz n).1.snd.snd.snd.snd := rfl
example (n : Nat) : let (g, e) := (baz n); e = g.snd.snd.snd.snd := rfl

Avoid nested (dependent) products
Looking again at your question, you say

I write a function that returns several values, proofs or functions, and I pack them in a nested dependent pair.

I would argue that returning deeply nested products, especially nested dependent products, is a code smell (even in regular functional programming).  Code like that is brittle and hard to follow.  I would recommend making a return structure type just for your function such as in the following example:
structure IncreasingTriple where
  a : Nat
  b : Nat
  c : Nat
  hab : b > a
  hbc : c > b

def consecutiveTriple (n : Nat) : IncreasingTriple where
  a := n
  b := n + 1
  c := n + 2
  hab := by simp
  hbc := by simp

def myFunction (n : Nat) : Unit :=
  let x := consecutiveTriple n
  let y := x.hbc
  ()

Notice the structure IncreasingTriple is like a dependent quintuple, but to get the last element, you can just call the field x.hbc by name.

I doubt this is a bug. I'm not familiar with the syntax of Lean, but in Coq this doesn't type either: fun ab : nat*nat => let (a, b) := ab in eq_refl : a = fst ab, and that's expected to me. match doesn't introduce a definitional equality between the subject and the pattern. Even a propositional equality might be ill-typed.

Yeah, the most would be a feature request.  Often (but maybe not in Lean), let x := e in f x is implemented as (lambda x, f x) e so you wouldn’t have the context about x = e when building f x.

In Coq, let x := u in v definitely uses the definition of x as u when type-checking v (I recently added an example to the documentation), but let <pattern> := ... in ... is different: it's syntactic sugar for pattern matching, and because of dependent pattern matching it may not be possible to get an equality.
